# Marginal Pdf from joint pdf of discrete variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

X,Y are random discrete variables with joint probability function of

$f(x,y) = \dfrac {1}{e^2\cdot y!\cdot (x-y)!} $ with $x \in\{ 0,1,2,...\}$ and $y\in\{0,1,2,...x\}$

Find marginals $f_X(x)$ , $f_Y(y)$.

I tried to compute firstly $f_Y(y)$ but i have a problem with the summation of the series:

$$f_Y(y) = \sum_{x=0}^\infty \dfrac {1}{e^2\cdot y!\cdot (x-y)!} = \frac {1}{e^2\cdot y!}\cdot \sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac {1}{(x-y)!} $$

How can I compute $f_Y(y)$ and $f_X(x)$ ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: $x \in \lbrace 0, 1 \ldots y \rbrace$ right ?

Comment: Well, for a start, that should be $\sum_{x=y}^\infty\ldots$ because $y\leq x$.

Comment: @Ahamad $x\in\{y,\ldots\}$

Comment: @GrahamKemp you mean $x \in \lbrace 0 \ldots \infty \rbrace$ right ?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi Yes x e {0... infinity}

Comment: @Ahamad For clarrity: The support is $(X,Y) \in \{(x,y)\in\Bbb N: y\leq x\}$, so the sum for the $Y=y$ marginal is $\sum\limits_{x\in\{y,..,\infty\}}$, or $\sum\limits_{x=y}^\infty$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The marginal $f_X(x)$ is 
$$f_X(x) =\frac{1}{e^2} \sum\limits_y \frac{1}{y!(x-y)!} = \frac{1}{x!e^2} \sum\limits_y \frac{x!}{y!(x-y)!} = \frac{1}{x!e^2} \sum\limits_y \binom{x}{y}(1)^y(1)^{x- y} = \frac{1}{x!e^2} (1+1)^{x} $$
So
$$f_X(x) =  \frac{1}{x!e^2} 2^x$$

Similarly 
$$f_Y(y) =\frac{1}{y!e^2} \sum\limits_{x=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x-y)!}=\frac{1}{y!e^2} \sum\limits_{x=y}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x-y)!}$$
where the last equation is because $ y \leq x$. Let $k = x - y$, you'd get
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{y!e^2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} =\frac{1}{y!e^2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1^k}{k!} = \frac{1}{y!e^2}e^1 = \frac{1}{ey!}$$
The sum of $\frac{1}{k!}$ becomes $e$ due to Taylor series.

Comment: Doesn't the infinite sum diverges in the third equality of your argument?

Comment: The implicit summation operator, $\sum\limits_y$ may be written explicitly as, $\sum\limits_{y=0}^x$.

Comment: @AhmadBazzi Thank you very much!!! very nice explanation. I think I have a problem with $f_y(y)$ too. Can you please post a sollution?

Comment: @venrey No, it sums up to $1$.

Comment: @brain_dead_cow i've edited